# Python writing to usb memory stick: [Errno 13] Permission denied (Android 11 tablet)

Tags: python, android

I'm writing a Python script to make a backup of the photos on my tablet (Android 11) to an USB memory stick (FAT32). I run the script with Pydroid3. To make my question simple, I reduced to script to the minimum.

Here is the code:

```
import shutil

source = r'/storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/img1.jpg' 
target = r'/dev/bus/usb/001/002/Pics'       

shutil.copyfile(source, target)
```

This results in the error:
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/dev/bus/usb/001/002/Pics'

I found the target path with the app 'PyTool USB serial free'.
SolideExplorer gives another path: '/mnt/media_rw/C087-2599/Pics',
but this gives the same error.

How can I solve this problem? Do I need to give Pydroid3 permission?
But how? In the script itself?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Use SAF to let the user choose the drive.

Comment: Thank you, Black apps, for your reply. I searched for more information about SAF, but most information is about SAF in Java scripts. I think this too complicated for me/ it will take too much time. I asked the developer of the PY3 app if he can change something. Hopefully he can do something. For now I let this little project go. Thanks again.